# How to build vs2008 c++ OpenCV dll to vs2008 C#?

Tags: c#, c++, opencv

I used the following reference:

https://drthitirat.wordpress.com/2013/05/30/combine-gui-of-c-with-c-codes/

... to try to use a vs2008 win32 project to build a C++ opencv dll, then open a new C# project to import the C++ dll.

In the C++ dll, I use OpenCV to read a image and use OpenCV to show the image.

C# imports the dll, and then runs, but it shows:

> HRESULT: 0x8007007E， the dll could not be found.

How can I resolve this issue?

Comment: Visual Studio's "Error Lookup" shows that that HRESULT to mean "The specified module could not be found."  With that information, you can start tracking that kind of problem in the normal way.  Process Monitor or FusLogVw should point you in the right direction

Answer (score 0):

Thank you Grant Miller

The problem :HRESULT: 0x8007007E is been solved.
I forgot to copy the tbb.dll to my project.

if C# project is release mode,just copy tbb.dll to the C# project.
if C# project is debug mode, change the tbb.dll's file name to tbb_debug.dll,then copy it to the C# project.

The tbb.dll's path will be in C:\opencv\build\common\tbb\ia32\vc9